# what does this paragraph mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> And as new nodes pour into the network, power laws
>   take over, allowing those providing the greatest value
>   to experience exponential rewards, with inactivity
>   pushing competitors towards insignificance.

I have problem in this part **pushing competitors towards insignificance** it is ambiguous for me.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what about this phrase is causing confusion for you? What do you think it might mean?

Comment: i think it mean the  those providing the greatest value to experience exponential rewards an others not gain this reward. it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell exactly what's meant without the full context, but your assessment is basically correct. *Inactivity* means that the competitors are failing to do something (to *provide value*). This failure to act causes the competitors to become insignificant as they lose customers the businesses that do *provide the greatest value*. The competitors lose out on that income.

Answer (score 0):

You description is of an **interconnected network** which is traversed.

There is some way of measuring **value** or **usefulness** at each node that is implied by **activity** (opposite of the reference to **inactivity**). Each node, when used (valued), receives a **reward** (possibly an increment in count) which increases exponentially (**power laws**). The **value** of a node may effect the number of times it is used, where **higher value equals more usage** (reenforcement), this in itself may cause the exponential increase in value.